# WPF Binding To Application Properties

Tags: wpf, binding

I need to bind to static properties in my App.xaml.cs class and have so far done this using:

```
Property="{Binding Source={x.Static Application.Current}, Path=SomePath}"
```

This works OK when the application is being run directly, but when the application is started from another application, these bindings don't work as I believe Application.Current then points at the parent application rather than the application that the xaml sits under.

How would I bind to the immediate App.xaml.cs file properties rather than those from the parent application?

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: What does "started from another application" mean? Is it in a different process?

Comment: I wasn't particularly clear on that one! i.e. Application1 has a reference to Application2. Then under Application1, something like Application2.MainWindow app2Main = new Application2.MainWindow(); is called.

Comment: in that case no instance of Application2 is ever created...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So one solution I've found so far is to put a class between App.xaml.cs and the XAML I'm trying to bind:

**App.xaml.cs:**

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public static string SomeText;

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        SomeText = "Here is some text";
    }
}
```

**MyProperties.cs:**

```
public class MyProperties
{
    public static string SomeText
    {
        get { return App.SomeText; }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MyProperties x:Key="properties"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource properties}, 
                              Path=SomeText}"/>
</Grid>
```

Any other suggestions are still more than welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

**App.xaml.cs:**

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public static string SomeText => "Here is some text";

}
```

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static Application.Current}, 
                              Path=SomeText}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).